# How can I target third child level of parent in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grbw4tcg/1/

I have a page that might have multiple grouped input blocks with a class, say "error_bx". I want to target the first element that has this class and within that, I want to check and see if it's third level child has a class called "uniform-select" and if it has it, then add the class "focus" to it.

I got till here so far, but I'm not sure how to use the variable 'firstError' in conjunction with traversing through child elements. Also, is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
var firstError = $('.error_bx').first();

if($(firstError).children().eq(0).hasClass("uniform-select")){
        $($(firstError).children().eq(0)).addClass("focus");//
    }
    else if($(firstError +' > div.row > div > div').hasClass("uniform-select")){

        $('div.error_bx > div.row > div > div').addClass("focus");
    }
    else{
        $($(firstError).children().eq(0)).focus();
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="formgrp error_bx">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="selector uniform-select">
                <select>
                    <option>Month</option>
                    <option>January</option>
                    <option>February</option>
                    <option>March</option>
                    <option>April</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formgrp">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="selector uniform-select fixedWidth">
                <select>
                    <option>Month</option>
                    <option>January</option>
                    <option>February</option>
                    <option>March</option>
                    <option>April</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formgrp error_bx">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="selector uniform-select">
                <select>
                    <option>Month</option>
                    <option>January</option>
                    <option>February</option>
                    <option>March</option>
                    <option>April</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formgrp error_bx">
    <div>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you can't use `find('.uniform-select').addClass('focus')` ?

Comment: I'm trying to find the 'uniform-select' that has an error. There might be a 'uniform-select' class without an error. So, it has to come through the first element that has the 'error_bx' class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JQuery dom traversal methods, listed here:
https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

On your fiddle I used this to target your pesky div:

```
var firstError = $('.error_bx').first();
f = firstError.children().children().children().eq(0);
```

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to see if there was a way to use the variable in this line: `if($(firstError +' > div.row > div > div').hasClass("uniform-select"))`

But this works just fine. Thanks again!